# Not getting Query String Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am facing problem to get variable from query string. I have used htaccess redirection for my page.

I have written following rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).htm$ category.php?uniqname=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).htm/$ category.php?uniqname=$1
```

what this rule is doing if I type `gold-plated-chain.htm` is browser that I am redirect to 
`category.php?uniqname=gold-plated-chain`
Now I want to pass one varible so I am doing this way `gold-plated-chain.htm?page=2` but I can't get page variable on category.php i am redirecting properly but without that page variable

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I /think/ what you're after is the QSA flag (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which should append query strings.

Try adding [QSA] to the end of your RewriteRule lines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [QSA] flag to tell the rewrite engine to merge the query strings.  It is always wise to add the [L] flag and specify a base.   It's also wise to escape "." characters as this is interpreted as a wild card  You can also combine these two rules.  Hence:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^([\w-/]+)\.htm/?$   category.php?uniqname=$1  [L,QSA]
```

BTW, `\w` is just a short-hand for `a-zA-Z0-9`.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove ^ from the regexp. It means the start of the string.